# Секундомер на js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код js секундомера:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Таймер</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init()
            {
                sec = 0;
                setInterval(tick, 1000);
            }
            
            function tick()
            {
                sec++;
                document.getElementById("timer").
                    childNodes[0].nodeValue = sec;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="timer">0</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

В этом коде секунды просто идут в перед.
Как сделать что бы был такой вид минуты:секундны, и после 60 сек была 1 мин, вообщем обычный секундомер.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как один из вариатов, обычный секундомер:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  StartStop();
}

//объявляем переменные
var base = 60;
var clocktimer, dateObj, dh, dm, ds, ms;
var readout = '';
var h = 1,
  m = 1,
  tm = 1,
  s = 0,
  ts = 0,
  ms = 0,
  init = 0;

//функция для очистки поля
function ClearСlock() {
  clearTimeout(clocktimer);
  h = 1;
  m = 1;
  tm = 1;
  s = 0;
  ts = 0;
  ms = 0;
  init = 0;
  readout = '00:00:00';
  document.MyForm.stopwatch.value = readout;
}

//функция для старта секундомера
function StartTIME() {
  var cdateObj = new Date();
  var t = (cdateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTime()) - (s * 1000);
  if (t > 999) {
    s++;
  }
  if (s >= (m * base)) {
    ts = 0;
    m++;
  } else {
    ts = parseInt((ms / 100) + s);
    if (ts >= base) {
      ts = ts - ((m - 1) * base);
    }
  }
  if (m > (h * base)) {
    tm = 1;
    h++;
  } else {
    tm = parseInt((ms / 100) + m);
    if (tm >= base) {
      tm = tm - ((h - 1) * base);
    }
  }
  ms = Math.round(t / 10);
  if (ms > 99) {
    ms = 0;
  }
  if (ms == 0) {
    ms = '00';
  }
  if (ms > 0 && ms <= 9) {
    ms = '0' + ms;
  }
  if (ts > 0) {
    ds = ts;
    if (ts < 10) {
      ds = '0' + ts;
    }
  } else {
    ds = '00';
  }
  dm = tm - 1;
  if (dm > 0) {
    if (dm < 10) {
      dm = '0' + dm;
    }
  } else {
    dm = '00';
  }
  dh = h - 1;
  if (dh > 0) {
    if (dh < 10) {
      dh = '0' + dh;
    }
  } else {
    dh = '00';
  }
  readout = dh + ':' + dm + ':' + ds;
  document.MyForm.stopwatch.value = readout;
  clocktimer = setTimeout("StartTIME()", 1);
}

//Функция запуска и остановки
function StartStop() {
  if (init == 0) {
    ClearСlock();
    dateObj = new Date();
    StartTIME();
    init = 1;
  } else {
    clearTimeout(clocktimer);
    init = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name=MyForm>
  <input name=stopwatch size=10 value="00:00:00.00" disabled>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Секундомер
//изначальные переменные
min = 0;
hour = 0;
//Оставляем вашу функцию
function init() {
    sec = 0;
    setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

//Основная функция tick()
function tick() {
    sec++;
    if (sec >= 60) { //задаем числовые параметры, меняющиеся по ходу работы программы
        min++;
        sec = sec - 60;
    }
    if (min >= 60) {
        hour++;
        min = min - 60;
    }
    if (sec < 10) { //Визуальное оформление
        if (min < 10) {
            if (hour < 10) {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML ='0' + hour + ':0' + min + ':0' + sec;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = hour + ':0' + min + ':0' + sec;
            }
        } else {
            if (hour < 10) {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0' + hour + ':' + min + ':0' + sec;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':0' + sec;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (min < 10) {
            if (hour < 10) {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0' + hour + ':0' + min + ':' + sec;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = hour + ':0' + min + ':' + sec;
            }
        } else {
            if (hour < 10) {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
            }
        }
    }
}
```